# draw transparent color in onDraw using Paint Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

hello every one i want to draw color on bitmap with the help of canvas and paint. Color draw on bitmap work fine but i want to draw transparent color that not work here is my application draw black color like below [image]

i tried from one week but not success i want to draw transparent color like below[image]

how could i do that any one is there who help me 
here is my drawView class

```
public class DrawView extends View {
public Bitmap mBitmap;
public Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
private Paint mPaint;
private Bitmap imgF;
private static float MIN_ZOOM = 1f;
private static float MAX_ZOOM = 1f;
private float scaleFactor = 1.f;
private ScaleGestureDetector detector;

public DrawView(Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setAlpha(200 * 5);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);

}


@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();

    imgF = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(MainActivity.gImg, canvas.getWidth(),
            canvas.getHeight(), true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgF, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    canvas.restore();
   }
}
```

here is my XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/transparent" <---- transparent background               
     // below the FrameLayout 

android:orientation="vertical" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/eraserFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0" >

    <com.dxd.bgeraser.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/eraserImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <View style="@style/ShadowBarTop" />

    <View style="@style/ShadowBarBottom" />
 </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the colour behind the image is black? 

This would give the impression that you were painting black when you are actually doing what you want to be doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that when you are saving the image compress format is **.png**

if

```
Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG
```

then replace it to

```
Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG
```

Answer (score 0):

Transparent color code is : #00000000 or you can use Color.TRANSPARENT

Comment: the background boxes is not a transparent color but an image...you have to add a background image like that and your paint color will be transparent.

Comment: background image like what ? the second screenshot i showed in image you mean?